# error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied on gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to pull code with gitlab-runner with a shell executor.

```
 $ git pull origin master
 error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

git status seems to work fine but when I try git fetch

```
 $ git fetch
 error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because you did not add a deploy key for your gitlab-runner user in your gitlab project, so the runner user does not have access to your gitlab repository.

You should follow theses steps to create the keypair for `gitlab-runner` user (the shell executor user) https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-shell-executor

Then copy the created public key in `/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

And add it to your gitlab project's deploy key :

- Go to you gitlab project
- Settings => Repository
- Deploy keys
- Add a title, past the public key and click "Add key"

Trigger you CI again and the shell executor runner should be able to pull the repository.

Answer (score -1):

I just solved this problem by running this command
`sudo chown -R $(whoami) .git/` in my project directory.

You can change `$(whoami)` to the username of your server. For example `sudo chown -R gitlab-runner .git/`

Answer (score -2):

Changing the permissions helped!

sudo chown -R  .git/

Comment: what permissions did you change to?